# Importing my blogger blog into Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, blogger, github-pages

I don't have any Ruby experience, so forgive my ignorance.
I'm trying to import my Blogger blog to a new created GitHun pages blog. I exported my blog contents already. I try to run this command:

ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import"; JekyllImport::Importers::Blogger.run({ "source" => "blog-05-21-2016.xml" })'

but I keep getting this error:

```
D:\GitHub\ebeid.github.io\blogger>ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import"; JekyllImport::Importers::Blogger.run({ "source" => "blog-05-21-2016.xml" })'
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting =>
...rters::Blogger.run({ "source" = })
...                               ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this import code into a .rb file named whatever you like.

```
require "jekyll-import";
        JekyllImport::Importers::Blogger.run({
          "source"                => "/path/to/blog-MM-DD-YYYY.xml",
          "no-blogger-info"       => false, # not to leave blogger-URL info (id and old URL) in the front matter
          "replace-internal-link" => false, # replace internal links using the post_url liquid tag.
        })
```

Then, run the code in Ruby Command Prompt using the following command (make sure you are in the directory this file is in and that the file is in the directory your Jekyll site is in.)

```
ruby -rubygems nameoffile.rb
```

The command that's listed on the Jekyll import page is basically telling RubyGems to run the code you put in the .rb file. By running `ruby -rubygems nameoffile.rb`, it acheives the same purpose, but instead of writing the code straight into cmd, you are giving it a file to run.

Sidenote: The importer will spit out html files into the post folder. At first, I thought it should have made .markdown files, but on closer inspection, the html file still works. You can just leave it there.

Comment: I have to translate from html to markdown and also edit the extension?

Comment: The import will automatically convert HTML to markdown. You will have to change the `/path/to/blog` into the path to your downloaded blog.xml file.